# ファイルサーバー上にあるファイルをローカルにDLする

Tags: network, smb

社内のファイルサーバーからエクセルファイルをローカルに落とすことが頻繁にあります。
サーバー上のファイルを直接閲覧することは禁止されているため、見るだけであってもローカルに落とす必要があるのですが、毎回、サーバーを見に行きコピペする作業が面倒なので、プログラム実行して自動でダウンロードできたらと思いました。

・サーバーのアドレスは`smb://`で始まる
・DLしたいファイルは主にエクセルファイル
・プログラム実行であらかじめ指定してあるファイルをサーバー上からデスクトップにコピー(上書き)

このようなことは可能でしょうか？また、どの言語が簡単でしょうか。
Node.jsやPythonでできれば新たに環境作る必要もないのでその方が良いですが、なんでもいいです。

ご回答のほど、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 質問内容からするにローカル環境はmacOSかなんかでしょうか、また「サーバー上のファイルを直接閲覧することは禁止」のポリシーがいまいち理解できないのですがこの設定意図などはご存知ですか?

Comment: ありそうな理由を推測すると、フォルダを綺麗に保ちたい、といったところでしょうか。直接閲覧すると作業用の一時ファイルが作られるし、そこでハングしたりするとゴミファイルが残るとか、オープン中のファイル/作業ファイルがあると、バックアップとかバッチ処理等で排他チェックに引っかかるとか。あとは誰のものとも分からないちょっとした名前違いのファイルが増えてどれが正しいものか分からなくなるとか。

Comment: 過去質問を見る限りは`macOS`を使っているように見えますが、この質問にもクライアント側で想定しているOSを明記してもらえると的確なアドバイスがしやすいですし、より親切かなと思います。

Answer (score 0):

Windowsに標準で付いてくる PowerShell で出来るでしょう。

リファレンスは英語ですが。
[Copy-Item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-6)

こんな解説記事があります。
[PowerShell の Copy-Item コマンドレットを使用して WinRM でファイル転送する方法](https://blog.ipswitch.com/jp/use-powershell-copy-item-cmdlet-transfer-files-winrm)

オプションなので入っていない場合は「コントロールパネル」「プログラムのアンインストール」「Windowsの機能の有効化または無効化」で「Windows PowerShell 2.0」を有効にするか、マイクロソフトのダウンロードセンター等から、もっと新しい版数のパッケージをダウンロードしてインストールすれば良いでしょう。

使用OS版数によってインストール可能な版数が変わると思いますが、最新版は6.0のようです。

検索すれば色々と使い方の記事が出てくると思います。

---

コメントを見たらmacのようですが、今ではmacやLinuxでもサポートしているので、
おそらく同様に使えるでしょう。使いたいかどうかは、まあお好みで。

[macOS への PowerShell Core のインストール](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-macos?view=powershell-6)
[Linux への PowerShell Core のインストール](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-linux?view=powershell-6)

[【連載】PowerShell Core入門 - 基本コマンドの使い方【第7回】ファイルやディレクトリの作成、削除、コピー、移動](https://news.mynavi.jp/itsearch/article/hardware/3734)
[クロスプラットフォーム対応したPowerShellをMac OS Xで試してみた](https://dev.classmethod.jp/server-side/powershell-macosx/)

Answer (score 0):

> あらかじめ指定してあるファイル

とのことなので、ファイル名は固定なのですね。

仮に `smb://hoge-server/share/sample.xlsx` というパスに置かれているとします。

この場合、

```
copy \\hoge-server\share\sample.xlsx sample.xlsx
```

という1行だけのBATファイルを作り、デスクトップに `copy_xlsx.bat` みたいな名前で保存しておき、必要になるたびダブルクリックすれば良いと思います。

この方法ならば、PowerShellと違って初めて実行する際に、特別に権限を与える必要がありません。

ただ、もしファイルパスに日本語が含まれていたら、「コピー元ファイルが見つからない」扱いになるため、この方法は使えません。